# Check if virtualization is enabled without sudo on Centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, virtualization, centos7

I need to check if virtualization is enabled without sudo on Centos 7.

I found commands to check if virtualization is enabled, but it needs sudo.

```
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr 0x3a
```

For Ubuntu exists utility cpu-checker which can check if virtualization is enabled without sudo.

```
kvm-ok
```

Does exist similar utility to cpu-checker on Centos 7?

Comment: `kvm-ok` is a shell script that also depends on the `rdmsr` binary for specific CPU registers checkups. This script looks portable accross Linuces. I guess you can copy it to CentOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:

`kvm-ok` and `rdmsr 0x3a` do completely different things.

`kvm-ok`, according to it's [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/kvm-ok.1.html) just parses `/proc/cpuinfo` for the CPU flags that indicate Virtualization technology in the CPU (and then checks whether the necessary module was loaded, whereas `rdmsr` reads special model-specific registers of the CPU.

Hence, `kvm-ok` doesn't do anything you'd need root privileges for, whereas `rdmsr` can't work because your process doesn't have to context to query these registers.

`rdmsr 0x3a` can be used, with a few tricks, to figure out whether on a intel Core iX or later XEON processor the VT technology was enabled; for performant virtualization, that is **necessary**, but not **sufficient**.

Hence, I'd say just go ahead and do what `kvm-ok` does manually.

Check for the first CPU's `vmx` or `svm` [flags](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h?id=refs/tags/v4.1.3):

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo|head -n1|grep -Eo '(vmx|svm)'
```

and verify the kvm model was loaded:

```
lsmod | grep '^kvm'
```

If you, in fact, actually need to query that model-specific register (for example, because for some reason, even with VT disabled in the UEFI settings, the `vmx` flag is present), the easiest way would certainly be just using the powers of sudo to specify the program `rdmsr` to be run **exactly** with the arguments `0x3a` by the user of your choice (let's call it `daemonuser`)without password (see `man sudoers`, or your `/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples/sudoers`):

```
daemonuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/rdmsr 0x3a
```